# Display table values in textboxes

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a table **UserProfile** which have fields-

**UserId,
 FirstName,
 LastName,
 Password, 
 EmailId,
 MobileNumber.**

Now I want that when I execute **select query** where userId is **A1001** in sql server.

It bring values of all the fields in textboxes. Like-

```
TextBox1.text = FirstName.value,

TextBox2.text = LastName.value
```

and so on.

How can I do this ?

Comment: What have you tried? Where in the process are you are experiencing a problem?

Comment: Get the values from the database and assign it to the Text property of the textboxes.

Comment: I am able to select all values using select query but how to keep firstname in txtbox1, lastname in txtbox2 and so on..

Comment: @Tanner Question is related to programming. How can you can it is off topic. If you do not  know, keep away.

Comment: @Azhar Shahid, yes we all know that this question is related to programming. Please read this [How to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: @josmk1e, he should say question is not asked properly, not off topic.

Comment: @AzharShahid obviously it's about programming, but you need to show some code, not ask open questions. Just read the link that jomsk1e sent and it tells you what you need to consider when asking a question

Comment: I have edited the question- Now any confusion.?

Comment: I have answer of this question. But how to answer this. It is not accepting answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this....

```
      using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnect))
            {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT  FirstName, LastName, EmailId, MobileNUmber FROM myTable WHERE id=@ID", con))
                {
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", iD);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
                da.Fill(dt);
                txtFirstName.Text = dt.Rows[0]["FirstName"];
                txtName.Text = dt.Rows[0]["LastName"];
                }
            }
```

Comment: what happened? its a just sample code to get understanding dont copy paste it change it according to requirement

Comment: Showing Exception-  No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox to a known managed provider native type

Comment: @Azhar Shahid Please accept answer if it is correct for other user understanding.